# Using select query with like operator and parameters in java

Tags: java, mysql, sql

I want to write this query:

```
SELECT * FROM products
WHERE name LIKE '%?%' 
OR description LIKE '%?%'
```

and execute it through java in spring web application. But here problem is when I use `LIKE` operator it has to be with literals, but when I write `'%?%'` java doesn't recognize `?` like placeholders for parameters, when I add parameters I get error that there is no parameters in my query.

Also if I write `%?%` without literals I get syntax error.

Comment: why can't you use '%:name%' and '%:description%', much better, more readable and resolves your problem

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can always use `concat()`:

```
SELECT *
FROM products
WHERE name LIKE CONCAT('%', ?, '%') OR
      description LIKE CONCAT('%', ?, '%');
```

Or use the application to put the wildcards in the pattern string.